# How do I declare type information outside of my .ts file?

Tags: typescript

I write all my code in `.ts` files.

But I don't want to declare *function* parameters and return-types inline. I still might want to use inline types for variables.

```
// Not types on the function.
function foo(bar) {
  // Maybe I type some things.
  const foo: number = 1  
}
```

I don't want this:

```
function foo(bar: BarType): FooReturnType {
  
}
```

Why? Because I find it makes the code harder to read.

Is this possible?

---

EDIT:

To address the "because I find it makes the code harder to read.":

JSDoc annotations might be an option: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html

As this allows specifying types on a complete separate line from the code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any way to combine external type declarations (e.g. in a `.d.ts` file) with `.ts` files, and have the code in the `.ts` file checked according to the externally declared type. However, I can suggest a couple of ways to declare the function's type in the `.ts` file without doing it inline in the function definition.

```
type FooType = (bar: BarType) => FooReturnType

const foo: FooType =
  function (bar): {
    // inferred type of bar is any
  }
```

If you're compiling without the flags `--strict` or `--no-implicit-any`, you could make use of TypeScript's function overloading syntax to declare the type separately from the implementation. Basically a trivially overloaded function with just one type

```
function foo(bar: string): number;

function foo(bar) {
  // inferred type of bar is any
}
```

However, that won't work in strict mode because the `bar` parameter in the implementation would need to be explicitly declared as `any`. Also, unlike the previously suggested method, the type of "bar" will be inferred as `any` inside the implementation body, instead of `BarType`.